# Javascript populate form after validation

Tags: javascript, forms

I am doing a form for my javascript class, and I am getting stuck on a certain portion of it. I have a separate validator javascript file and call the function on the html file. All the validation works if the form areas are not filled in. What I want to do is if the fields are left blank they will fail the validation and will insert a value into that field. Below are an example of the form field, javascript function in the html page, and the external validator js file.

call function in html head:

```
function formvalidation(thisform) {
with (thisform) {
if (textbox_validation(first_name,"Please enter your first name.")==false)
{first_name.blur(); return false;};
if (textbox_validation(business_name,"Please enter your business. Please enter N/A if 
you do not have one.")==false) { business_name.focus(); return false; 
business_name.value=="N/A";};
```

The external js validator:

```
function textbox_validation(entered, alertbox) {
with (entered) {
if (value==null || value=="") {
  alert(alertbox);
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
   }
  }
}
```

So the validator works and focuses on the empty fields, but for some of my fields I want them to fill themselves with a certain value if validation fails or if it isnt filled int. The business_name line of code is when I tried to make it work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use of `with` is generally discouraged. Source: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarilly, you wouldn't use alert, but would instead put error messages in a `span` or `div` either near the `input` or at the top (or bottom) of the `form`. Additionally (as mentioned by [@Frits van Campen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722762/frits-van-campen)) it is  **[generally bad practice to use `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description)** 
Try something like this instead:

```
function textbox_validation(entered, errormsg) {
    var errbox = document.getElementById(entered.id + '-errors'); // just to prevent writing it twice
    // Note this requires the input to have an id, and the errer box's id to be the same with an '-errors' suffix.

    // Instead of using with, just acces properties normally
    if (!entered.value) { // The `!` "neggation" operater makes "falsy" values `true`
                      // "falsy" values include `false`, the empty string, `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` and a few others
        // Put the error message in the DOM instead of alerting it
        errbox.innerHTML = errormsg;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // Wipe any previous error messages
        errbox.innerHTML = '';
        return true;
    }
}
```

And for the form validator, again; let's not use `with`. But also, when attempting to assing "N/A" to the value, you've used the **comparison** operator instead of the **assignment** operator, and you've done it **after returning**:

```
function formvalidation(thisform) {
    // just use the `!` "negation" operator
    if (!textbox_validation(thisform.first_name,
        "Please enter your first name."))
    {
        thisform.first_name.blur();
        return false;
    }
    if (!textbox_validation(business_name,
        "Please enter your business. Please enter N/A if you do not have one."))
    {
        thisform.business_name.focus();
        thisform.business_name.value = "N/A"; // for assignment, use `=`. `==` and `===` are used for comparison
        return false; // a return statement ends the function, make sure it's after anything you want to execute!
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed your post, and I just read about not using with. I will use this instead. How exactly do I create and display a different error message for each input?

Comment: @user2532765 To create the error message just pass it to textbox_validate (like you're already doing). To create the _error message box_ `HTML`, try something like `<input id="foo"/><span id="foo-error"></span>` note the similar `id`s and the `getElementById(entered.id + '-errors')` obviously you would change _`foo`_ to the `id` you are already using for each input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM to set the placeholder for the fields. Like this.

```
 var myInput = document.getElementById('input1');
 myInput.placeholder = 'This validation has failed.';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Where exactly would I put that code in the HTML or external JS file? And input1 would be my fields id like first_name?

Comment: put it in your external js file after the `alert(alertBox);`. Yes, input1 refers to an id you will set for the input fields you want it to show for. Remember that each input field has to have a different id.